# How does the current loop exert force on itself in the Hall Effect experiment?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism

I recently read about Hall effect. My understanding of it is that when a current loop is placed in an external magnetic field, its electrons experience a magnetic force. This creates a charge separation in the wire and an electric field is induced inside the wire. This electric field exerts a force on the lattice of the wire, making it move.

[image]

Now the thing that's confusing me is how can an internal force (the electric force in this case i.e. $i(\vec{dl})\times\vec{B}$ produce acceleration?

My first resort was to try to find the third law pair of the electric force and on which body it applies but I failed to do it. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: You description seems wrong. Electric field of the separated surface charge has close to negligible effect on the lattice motion, because it is electrostatic field and forces due to that field obey 3rd law, and thus they cancel out. Motor effect (ponderomotive force on the conductor body) is due to forces due to current particles acting on the surface charge and the lattice. Also, in EM theory magnetic force does not, in general, obey 3rd law.

Comment: @JánLalinský Could you dumb this down for a high schooler? My teacher basically said that Magnetic Field can't exert force on the lattice because it is at rest but the induced electrostatic force can still act on it and produce motion. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Electrostatic force, in general, can produce motion. However, change of motion of current-carrying wire in magnetic field is due to macroscopic magnetic force due to external bodies (sources of magnetic field), acting on the current-forming particles. However, it is true that those particles can't jump out of the conductor, so they push/pull on the lattice and it's these forces which act on the lattice and cause change of its motion. Some of these internal forces are electrostatic, but some are not (constraint forces keeping the current particles attached to the conductor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simpler case, namely a wire that is above and parallel to another wire with current in the opposite direction (so the wires repel each other).  How does the lower wire push the upper wire up?  The moving electrons in the upper wire are pushed upward, but they are held in the wire by atomic interactions.  So they pull the rest of the wire up with them.  Those atomic interactions may be the internal electric force you are thinking of.

As a more concrete analogy, consider a book sitting on a table.  Gravity pulls down on each bit of the book, but the table only interacts with the bottom surface of the book.  Internal forces keep the book's shape, so the bottom of the book pushes up the middle and the middle pushes up the top.  In this way you could say internal forces are pushing the book up against gravity, but ultimately there's an external force from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Am looking at [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect). Although not explicitly stated in it, when $\vec{B}$ is added, an electric charge distribution is generated on the surface, resulting in $-\nabla\phi$, which cancels the EMF ($\vec{v}\times{B}$) in the y-direction.
\begin{equation}
F_y=q\left(-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}+(\vec{v}\times\vec{B})_y\right)=0
\end{equation}
This is similar to [the open circuit problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/679965/how-is-emf-still-induced-in-an-incomplete-open-circuit/681436#681436), $-\nabla\phi$ cancels EM electric field.
In this case, $V_H$ will be the differcence of $\phi$, i.e., $|V_H|=|\phi(y=0)-\phi(y=w)|$. Since the force is zero, the acceleration is zero.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a misunderstanding about the Hall effect. The Hall effect occurs when a current-carrying conductor is placed in a perpendicular magnetic field. Due to the magnetic field, the moving charge carriers (such as electrons) inside the conductor experience a magnetic force called the Lorentz force. This force causes the charge carriers to accumulate on one side of the conductor, creating a charge separation and an electric field (Hall field) perpendicular to both the current and the magnetic field.

This internal electric field exerts an electric force on the charge carriers inside the conductor. The force due to the electric field opposes the magnetic force acting on the charge carriers, and an equilibrium is reached when these forces balance each other. At this point, there is no net acceleration of the charge carriers. The Hall voltage is the voltage difference between the sides of the conductor due to the electric field and can be measured.

Concerning your question about the third law pair of the electric force, it is essential to understand that the internal electric field is created by the charge separation within the conductor. The electric force acting on the charge carriers is equal and opposite to the force exerted by the charge carriers on the rest of the conductor. The third law pair is within the conductor itself, as the forces are between the charge carriers and the rest of the conductor's lattice.